# How to call Cordova plugin using Angular without Ionic

Tags: android, angular, cordova, google-geolocation

I built a PWA in Angular 6 and was intending to use the Google Maps API for geolocation purposes.  However, I soon realized that the geolocation services in a PWA only work when the user is interacting with the UI to deliberately request their location.  My app is supposed to track the user's location in the background as they drive around, however.  So when they lock the screen or go to a different application it should still track them.  For the record, this is a private application and users are fully aware that they are being tracked.  As a result, I converted the PWA to a hybrid app using Cordova.  Everything works so far with what I had already (emulation is fine, etc), but I can't seem to figure out how to add the geolocation piece.  I have installed [this](https://github.com/mauron85/cordova-plugin-background-geolocation) plugin, which appears to be installed and available.  All of the examples I have seen use Ionic (which I don't need at this point) and are for the scenario where the user clicks a button to get their location, but I need it where the geolocation stuff is in a service and starts running in the background after they are logged in.  I can't seem to find something that shows how to do this.  Here's what I was thinking I should do:

(this isn't complete, I just pasted the example code from GitHub here and intend to fill it in with "stuff" when I know it's actually being called)

_services/geolocation.service.ts:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';

declare var cordova: any;

@Injectable()
export class GeolocationService {
  startBackgroundGeolocation() {
    console.log("Geolocation service called...");
    cordova.plugins.BackgroundGeolocation.configure({
      locationProvider: cordova.plugins.BackgroundGeolocation.ACTIVITY_PROVIDER,
      desiredAccuracy: cordova.plugins.BackgroundGeolocation.HIGH_ACCURACY,
      stationaryRadius: 50,
      distanceFilter: 50,
      notificationTitle: 'Background tracking',
      notificationText: 'enabled',
      debug: true,
      interval: 10000,
      fastestInterval: 5000,
      activitiesInterval: 10000,
      url: 'http://192.168.0.3:3000/location',
      httpHeaders: {
        'X-FOO': 'bar'
      },
      // customize post properties
      postTemplate: {
        lat: '@latitude',
        lon: '@longitude',
        foo: 'bar' // you can also add your own properties
      }
    });

    cordova.plugins.BackgroundGeolocation.on('location', function(location) {
      // handle your locations here
      // to perform long running operation on iOS
      // you need to create background task
      cordova.plugins.BackgroundGeolocation.startTask(function(taskKey) {
        // execute long running task
        // eg. ajax post location
        // IMPORTANT: task has to be ended by endTask
        cordova.plugins.BackgroundGeolocation.endTask(taskKey);
      });
    });

    cordova.plugins.BackgroundGeolocation.on('stationary', function(stationaryLocation) {
      // handle stationary locations here
    });

    cordova.plugins.BackgroundGeolocation.on('error', function(error) {
      console.log('[ERROR] cordova.plugins.BackgroundGeolocation error:', error.code, error.message);
    });

    cordova.plugins.BackgroundGeolocation.on('start', function() {
      console.log('[INFO] cordova.plugins.BackgroundGeolocation service has been started');
    });

    cordova.plugins.BackgroundGeolocation.on('stop', function() {
      console.log('[INFO] cordova.plugins.BackgroundGeolocation service has been stopped');
    });

    cordova.plugins.BackgroundGeolocation.on('authorization', function(status) {
      console.log('[INFO] cordova.plugins.BackgroundGeolocation authorization status: ' + status);
      if (status !== cordova.plugins.BackgroundGeolocation.AUTHORIZED) {
        // we need to set delay or otherwise alert may not be shown
        setTimeout(function() {
          var showSettings = confirm('App requires location tracking permission. Would you like to open app settings?');
          if (showSettings) {
            return cordova.plugins.BackgroundGeolocation.showAppSettings();
          }
        }, 1000);
      }
    });

    cordova.plugins.BackgroundGeolocation.on('background', function() {
      console.log('[INFO] App is in background');
      // you can also reconfigure service (changes will be applied immediately)
      cordova.plugins.BackgroundGeolocation.configure({ debug: true });
    });

    cordova.plugins.BackgroundGeolocation.on('foreground', function() {
      console.log('[INFO] App is in foreground');
      cordova.plugins.BackgroundGeolocation.configure({ debug: false });
    });

    cordova.plugins.BackgroundGeolocation.on('abort_requested', function() {
      console.log('[INFO] Server responded with 285 Updates Not Required');
      cordova.plugins.BackgroundGeolocation.stop();
      // Here we can decide whether we want stop the updates or not.
      // If you've configured the server to return 285, then it means the server does not require further update.
      // So the normal thing to do here would be to `cordova.plugins.BackgroundGeolocation.stop()`.
      // But you might be counting on it to receive location updates in the UI, so you could just reconfigure and set `url` to null.
    });

    cordova.plugins.BackgroundGeolocation.on('http_authorization', () => {
      console.log('[INFO] App needs to authorize the http requests');
    });

    cordova.plugins.BackgroundGeolocation.checkStatus(function(status) {
      console.log('[INFO] cordova.plugins.BackgroundGeolocation service is running', status.isRunning);
      console.log('[INFO] cordova.plugins.BackgroundGeolocation services enabled', status.locationServicesEnabled);
      console.log('[INFO] cordova.plugins.BackgroundGeolocation auth status: ' + status.authorization);

      // you don't need to check status before start (this is just the example)
      if (!status.isRunning) {
        cordova.plugins.BackgroundGeolocation.start(); //triggers start on start event
      }
    });

    // you can also just start without checking for status
    // cordova.plugins.BackgroundGeolocation.start();

    // Don't forget to remove listeners at some point!
    // cordova.plugins.BackgroundGeolocation.events.forEach(function(event) {
    //   return cordova.plugins.BackgroundGeolocation.removeAllListeners(event);
    // });
  }

}
```

Then from app.component:

```
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
    import {
      transition,
      trigger,
      query,
      style,
      animate,
      group,
      animateChild
    } from '@angular/animations';
    import { GeolocationService } from './_services/geolocation.service';

    declare const device;

    @Component({
      selector: 'app-root',
      templateUrl: './app.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
      animations: [
        trigger('routeAnimation', [
          transition('* => *', [
            query(
              ':enter',
              [style({ opacity: 0 })],
              { optional: true }
            ),
            query(
              ':leave',
               [style({ opacity: 1 }), animate('0.3s', style({ opacity: 0 }))],
              { optional: true }
            ),
            query(
              ':enter',
              [style({ opacity: 0 }), animate('0.3s', style({ opacity: 1 }))],
              { optional: true }
            )
          ])
        ])
      ]
    })

    export class AppComponent implements OnInit{
      title = 'HLD Phlebotomist App';

  constructor(private geolocationService: GeolocationService) { }

      ngOnInit() { 
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", function() {
          this.geolocationService.startBackgroundGeolocation();
          alert(device.platform);
        }, false); 
      } 
    }
```

However, when I run this in an android emulator, I get "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'startBackgroundGeolocation' of undefined".  No idea why.  Can someone help me understand the structure here?  I think my problem is that I don't totally understand how to "call" the Cordova plugin.

Answer (score 7):

I'm writing this here because I struggled to find these answers in a single place and pieced them together from various blog posts and stackoverflow posts all of which seemed incomplete some how.

**(1) Very Important Bootstrapping**

A source of continual bugs and head ache turned out to be that in certain conditions Angular and the core App would be bootstrapped before the mobile device (both android and iOS) were ready to provide access to system resources like the camera. This was something that I danced around with until finally adding SSO as a first step in our app made me confront the problem in more than 75% of loading scenarios

The solution here is pretty straight forward in the main.ts of your angular application add a javascript document.addEventListener that waits for cordova to say the device is ready before bootstrapping angular.

```
document.addEventListener('deviceready', bootstrap, false);
```

We have actually taken this one step further by adding a conditional block that injects the cordova script tag only when we turn it on in our environment variable. This made it easier to test non cordova features using ng serve in our test environment.

```
const bootstrap = () => platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule).catch(e => console.error(e));
const bootstrapCordova = () => {
  /** Dynamically load cordova JS **/
  console.log('bootstrapped cordova');

  const script = document.createElement('script');
  script.type = 'text/javascript';
  script.src = 'cordova.js';

  document.head.appendChild(script);

  if (script['readyState']) {
    // IE 2018 and earlier (?). They're migrating to using Chromium under the hood, so this may change
    script['onreadystatechange'] = () => {
      if (script['readyState'] === "loaded" || script['readyState'] === "complete") {
        document.addEventListener('deviceready', bootstrap, false);

      }
    };
  } else {
    // All other browsers
    document.addEventListener('deviceready', bootstrap, false);
  }
};
environment.cordova ? bootstrapCordova() : bootstrap();
```

**(2) Recognizing typings**

Since cordova and its plugins aren't bootstrapped as part of Angular it self we need to add cordova typings to our Angular project. While it is possible to write code without this using "window" functions in a particular way we found that important the typings solved lots of problems. Thankfully someone has contributed typescript typings to almost every single core cordova plugin. We tried just installing these typings in a types file but found that angular would grumble at compile time about having types but no library. For the record we don't feel like the following method should work but time and again they were the only replicable steps that got angular to stop grumbling.

First, we maintain our angular app in a separate filespace from cordova we then write the app to the www folder when ever we run ng build --prod. this means that our cordova app and our angular app each have a unique package.json to manage npm dependencies. in order to get access to cordova typings in angular we need to add cordova and all of the plugins we are using to the package.json of our angular project.

```
"cordova": "latest",
"cordova-plugin-camera": "latest",
"cordova-plugin-inappbrowser": "latest"
```

Second - once you have installed these dependencies we need to generate a typings file for our project. its worth noting that the "typings" package is deprecated in npm in favor of "@types" . however we weren't able to figure out how to accomplish the end result we wanted with "@types" so for now we are using "typings"

```
npm install –g typings
typings search cordova
typings install dt~cordova --global --save
```

This will generate a typings folder where ever you run the command so we recommend doing that in the root of your angular project. Once this is in place add the types file to your tsconfig.app.json and you are good to start coding.

```
"types": [
  "./typings/globals/cordova"
]
```

Third - file level import

in our research we saw lots of ways to implement typings at a code level but only one worked in our project. Logic would dictate that we should be able to do a simple:

```
import {*} from 'typings/globals/cordova'
```

and while our ide was fine with this ng build --prod was not. instead we reference the typings file in the following way:

```
/// <reference path="../../../../typings/globals/cordova/index.d.ts" />
```

once we had done this we were able to benefit from full intellisense in our IDE.

```
export class SplashComponent implements AfterViewInit, OnDestroy {
  private browser: InAppBrowser;
  private cordova: Cordova;

  constructor(private route: Router) {
    this.cordova = window['cordova']
this.browser = this.cordova.InAppBrowser;
  }

  ngAfterViewInit(){
      this.currentBrowser = this.browser.open('https://www.google.com', '_blank', 'location=yes');
}

}
```

**(3) Building cordova**

If you haven't seen it anywhere else know that the best way to handle any remaining issues you encounter with builds in cordova is to remove you platform and add it again.

```
cordova platform rm android
cordova platform add android
```

Using this workflow we were able to eliminate almost 100% of the runtime errors we experienced with our app and performance of our app skyrocketed.

Hopefully if you are having these issues you find this post helpful since its all the things I wish existed.

Notes: 
The proper Angular way to handle the "window" elements of this code is to use an injection token. I haven't included it here because this was a long post. I may update it later to include this.

Comment: If I understand correctly, it is possible to have angular project inside the cordova project? Then you run "ng serve" running only the angular project (beforehand setting environment variable ). What you use to run the cordova project, in order cordova to use the angular code? I am keeping angular and cordova in separate projects and I build angular with output path = the cordova project.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here was that the Cordova CLI was pulling version 2.x of the plugin, but the documentation was for 3.x.  In 2.x, the plugin file was backgroundGeolocation.js, whereas 3.x changes it to BackgroundGeolocation.js, and adds a BackgroundGeolocation.d.ts file to support TypeScript implementations.  Being that it's case-sensitive, it was being called by the wrong name and failing.  Adding @latest to my `cordova plugin add <plugin-name>` command pulled down the correct version and it started working.